# unable to save the value in form in mysql DB using PHP PDO

Tags: php

I have a form, where one of the fields have a predefined value (using php echo). I am trying to save the form, such that all the values are stored in DB.

But, the predefined value is showing Blank values, & hence not getting saved.

I am getting error message which says:

> **Undefined index** userid

and

> **SQLSTATE[23000]:** Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'vd_user_id' cannot be null

**Code:**

```
<?php    
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$STM = $conn ->prepare("SELECT * FROM vendorusers WHERE vd_user_email = :email");

$STM->bindParam(':email',$email);
$STM->execute();

$rows = $STM->fetchAll();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
$username = $row['vd_user_name'];
$userid = $row['vd_user_id'];
?>

<form name="userForm" role="form" action="" method="post" novalidate>
    <!-- text input -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Restaurant Name</label>


        <input type="text" class="form-control"  id = "username" name = "username[]" value= "<?php echo $username; ?>" disabled>


    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>User ID </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  id = "userid" name = "userid" value= "<?php echo $userid; ?>" disabled>
        <?php  } ?>


    </div>

    <div class="box box-danger">
        <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">Location</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Address Line 1" id = "Add1" name = "Add1" required>
            <br>

            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Address Line 2" id = "Add2" name = "Add2">
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <select class="form-control" id = "City" name = "City">
                        <option>City</option>
                        <option>Chennai</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <!-- select -->
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <select class="form-control" id = "State" name = "State">
                        <option>State</option>
                        <option>Tamil Nadu</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pin Code" maxlength="6" id = "PinCode" name = "PinCode">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
    </div><!-- /.box -->

    <div class="modal-footer clearfix"">

    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"value = "Save" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"  style="float: right>
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope" ></i>Save</button>
    </div>
</form>

<?php

try {

    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST["submit"])=="Save") {

        // Define Variables

        $userid = $_POST['userid'];
        echo $userid; //giving blank values
        $Logo = $_POST['logo'];
        $Add1 = $_POST['Add1'];

        $Add2 = $_POST['Add2'];
        $City = $_POST['City'];
        $State = $_POST['State'];
        $PinCode = $_POST['PinCode'];

        // Prepare the Query to save the data into the table


        $PROFILE = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO vendorprof (
                                                                                 vd_user_id,
                                                                                 vd_user_logo,
                                                                                 vd_loc_add1,
                                                                                 vd_loc_add2,
                                                                                 vd_loc_city,
                                                                                 vd_loc_state,
                                                                                 vd_loc_pin
                                                                                 )

                                                                          VALUES (
                                                                                  :userid,
                                                                                  :Logo,
                                                                                  :Add1,
                                                                                  :Add2,
                                                                                  :City,
                                                                                  :State,
                                                                                  :PinCode
                                                                                  )");

        // Bind the Parameters

        $PROFILE->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
        $PROFILE->bindParam(':Logo', $Logo);
        $PROFILE->bindParam(':Logo', $Logo);
        $PROFILE->bindParam(':Add1', $Add1);
        $PROFILE->bindParam(':Add2', $Add2);
        $PROFILE->bindParam(':City', $City);
        $PROFILE->bindParam(':State', $State);
        $PROFILE->bindParam(':PinCode', $PinCode);


        // Execute the Query
        $PROFILE->execute();

    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Sounds like maybe your `vd_user_id` column is `NOT NULL` and you are inserting `$userid` which is `null` or `false`? Just a guess.

Comment: It's probably null because that field is set as `disabled`?

Comment: You might be trying to hide those fields (maybe??) in that case use `type="hidden"`

Comment: yeah..I get it now.. Its because the field is set as disabled. But I don't want to hide the fields. I want it to display the value but the user shouldn't be able to edit the value.
In that case what is the alternative to save the displayed value in db?

Answer (score 0):

For userid tag, you have used keyword `disabled`.
Disabled inputs are never posted.

So either remove `disabled` or access `$userid` directly in your code.
Seems `$userid` is accessible after:
`if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST["submit"])=="Save") {`

Comment: Thanks!! The issue is resolved.
The issue was because of the disabled inputs. I tried using hidden, and it worked.. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

To make the input save to post, you could do a javascript or you could just do a hidden value with an `echo` after, similar to:

```
<form name="userForm" role="form" action="" method="post" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Restaurant Name</label>
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  id = "username" name = "username[]" value= "<?php echo $username; ?>" />
        <?php echo $username; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>User ID </label>
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  id = "userid" name = "userid" value= "<?php echo $userid; ?>" />
        <?php echo $userid; ?>
        <?php  } ?>
    </div>
```